# How can I manage the SiteEditURL parameter through DTAP

Tags: experience-manager

In order to configure Experience Manager, you add a SiteEditURL to the parameters of the "Enable inline editing for Page" TBB. This refers to your content manager server in a specific environment. Obviously, you don't want your production site to be referencing your development system, and this is not something that by default the content porter would be expected to take care of.

What is the best way of managing this?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to specify the SiteEdit URL as a parameter on the TBB. You can simply have a common TBB push a value into the package *with the same name*, loaded from wherever you like - a config file, or more practical in scaled out scenarios, a environment specific configuration component.

The Get System Components TBB on [Tridion World](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/generic-2011-tbbs.aspx) can be used to do this, just make sure you have a component with XML field name matching the SiteEdit TBB parameter name.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing I've found to do is to wrap this TBB in a Compound TBB and
use the latter in all your CTs instead of adding the former directly.

e.g. call this wrapper something like "Enable Inline Editing Config Wrapper".  You would then set your SiteEditURL inside the wrapper and the setting would therefore persist across all templates that use the wrapper.

So when it comes to DTAP, you only have to maintain/change the SIteEditURL in one place after content porting.

Comment: I'd vote up, but can't separate the answer from the joke. ;-)

Comment: edited the joke out.

Answer (score 2):

I like to have configuration files on my server - for a static publishing solution you could store the values in the contentmanager config files, or in a dd4t solution it could be in the extended classpath in a properties file.

Comment: I would also add that we could create machine specific variables that can be used in the CMS side, apart from using the Tridion CM config files.